# CQWP in sharePoint online public facing website

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-query-web-part, public-website

Is there a way to insert a CQWP to the page in SharePoint online public facing website?

Comment: Hit one on Google: http://office.microsoft.com/en-nz/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/websites-in-sharepoint-online-and-sharepoint-server-HA102828142.aspx#_Toc355768411 See comparison, web part is not available in SP Online Public facing web site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Website feature comparison](http://office.microsoft.com/en-nz/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/websites-in-sharepoint-online-and-sharepoint-server-HA102828142.aspx#_Toc355768411) table Content Query Web Part is **not** supported in SharePoint Online Web Site.

But, you could consider the following approach:

1. import CQWP web part into SharePoint Online Web Site (export it first, for example, from private site collection)
2. Add exported web part on the page (see the figure below)

**Result**

The following figure demonstrates CQWP configured to display Blog posts in SharePoint Online Web Site

[image]